# Bootstrap radio group jquery validation

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

Ive searched around, but couldnt get to find an answer as to how I could check using jquery validation that one of the buttons is MUST selected in a bootstrap radio button group before submission.

I have this as part of the form,

```
<div id="inputNumDel" name="inputNumDel" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
        <button type="button" id="num7"  class="btn ">7</button>
        <button type="button" id="num8"  class="btn ">8</button>
</div>
```

which gives this [image]

and this is the validation code which is NOT working

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $("#form").validate({
                rules:{                     
                    inputNumDel:{
                            required:true,
                    },

            },          
            errorClass: "help-block"
            });

     });
```

Comment: Your problem is improper usage of the plugin.  `type="button"` is not the same as `type="radio"`, and is not supported.  See http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use jquery validate to make a button element 'required'.

You will need a checkbox or a radio button or other input element.  jQuery mobile has a checkboxradio widget that has a similar effect, but uses radio buttons or checkboxes.

Answer (score 3):

I had to solve the same issue, and have posted my workaround on a similar question, here:

[jQuery validation against twitter bootstrap button group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317193/jquery-validation-against-twitter-bootstrap-button-group/19230940#19230940)

While you can't validate the buttons themselves (or indeed your button group div), you can use the buttons to store their value in a hidden field, then validate the hidden field instead.

Here is a working example, which I made for the above linked answer: http://jsfiddle.net/geekman/W38RG/18/

Basically, you want to do the following:

- Add a hidden field, just below your btn-group DIV. Use a click event on the buttons in your btn-group and set the value of your hidden field to some corresponding value, depending on the button.
- Then use jQuery validate to validate again the hidden field *instead of* your button group.
- Call `validate()` with the option to **not** ignore hidden fields.

So something like:

```
<div id="inputNumDel" name="inputNumDel" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button type="button" id="num7" value="7"class="btn ">7</button>
    <button type="button" id="num8" value="8" class="btn ">8</button>
</div>
<!-- Notice here that I have marked the hidden field as required, so jQuery validate should recognise it as required, allowing you to leave out your required rule -->
<input required type="hidden" id="inputNum" required="required" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Bind the click event to the parent div containing both buttons. Tell it to fire on any element containing the class btn.
    $('#inputNumDel').on('click', '.btn', function () {
        $('#inputNum').val($(this).val());
    });

    $('#form').validate({
        ignore: [],
        errorClass: "help-block"
    });
});
</script>
```